# Get a Document Set's description field via the REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api, document-set

I need to get the description field from my list of document sets. I have a for-loop set up with the titles of each of the document sets, I now just need to query the REST API to return a description for each set.

The current URL I am trying to use is:  `http://site.com/projects/_api/lists/GetByTitle('DocumentSetList')/items/?$select=Description`

But it does not seem to return the data I need, does anyone know how I can get the description field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal name of document set description is `DocumentSetDescription`. So, you have to use the API like:

```
http://site.com/projects/_api/lists/GetByTitle('DocumentSetList')/items/?$select=DocumentSetDescription
```

You can get the internal name of any of your SharePoint columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: When I run this command in PowerShell: `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://site.com/projects/_api/lists/GetByTitle('DocumentSetLists')/items/?$select=DocumentSetDescription" -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials -Method GET ` 
I get the following output: 

`etag        : "1"
id            : ...
category : category
link         : {link, link, link...}`

how do I get the actual data from the API? Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: Try using command in this format: `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://site.com/projects/_api/lists/GetByTitle('DocumentSetLists')/items/?$select=Title,DocumentSetDescription" -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials -Method GET | Format-Table -Property Title, DocumentSetDescription`

Comment: Check [Invoke-RestMethod](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) documentation for more information.